# How to write Query to retrieve every subdocument array who matches

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here i need my explain my problem clearly. How can i write a query to retrieve every subdocument array who matches the condition using mongoose and nodejs.

this is my existing JSON:

```
[
{
    _id: "568ccd6e646489f4106470ec",
    area_name: "Padi",
    warehouse_name: "Hapserve Online Water Service",
    name: "Ganesh",
    email: "ganesh@excrin.com",
    mobile_no: "9042391491",
    otp: "4466",
    __v: 0,
    date: "06-01-2016",
    booking: 
    [
        {
            can_quantity: "4",
            delivery_date: "06-01-2016",
            delivery_timeslot: "10am-3pm",
            subscription: "true",
            subscription_type: "Weekly",
            total_cost: "240",
            order_id: "S13833",
            can_name: "Tata Waters",
            address: "15/A,Ramanrajan street,,Padi,Chennai",
            can_cost: "240",
            _id: "568ccd6e646489f4106470ee",
            ordered_at: "2016-01-06T08:16:46.825Z",
            status: "UnderProcess"
        },
        {
            can_name: "Bisleri",
            can_quantity: "4",
            can_cost: "200",
            delivery_date: "11-01-2016",
            delivery_timeslot: "3pm-8pm",
            order_id: "11537",
            address: "27,Main Street,Padi,Chennai",
            _id: "5693860edb988e241102d196",
            ordered_at: "2016-01-11T10:38:06.749Z",
            status: "UnderProcess"
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id: "56937fb8920629a0164604d8",
    area_name: "Poonamallee",
    warehouse_name: "Tata Waters",
    name: "M.Kalaiselvan",
    email: "kalai131192@gmail.com",
    mobile_no: "9003321521",
    otp: "2256",
    __v: 0,
    date: "2016-01-11T10:11:04.266Z",
    booking: 
    [
        {
            can_quantity: "4",
            delivery_date: "06-01-2016",
            delivery_timeslot: "10am-3pm",
            subscription: "true",
            subscription_type: "Alternate",
            total_cost: "640",
            order_id: "S13406",
            can_name: "Kinley",
            address: "133,Bajanai koil street, Melmanagar,Poonamallee,Chennai",
            can_cost: "160",
            _id: "56937fb8920629a0164604da",
            ordered_at: "11-01-2016",
            status: "UnderProcess"
        },
        {
            can_name: "Tata Waters",
            can_quantity: "2",
            can_cost: "120",
            delivery_date: "11-01-2016",
            delivery_timeslot: "10am-3pm",
            order_id: "11387",
            address: "140,Bajanai koil street, Melmanagar,Poonamallee,Chennai",
            _id: "56937ff7920629a0164604dc",
            ordered_at: "2016-01-11T10:12:07.719Z",
            status: "UnderProcess"
        },
        {
            can_name: "Bisleri",
            can_quantity: "4",
            can_cost: "200",
            delivery_date: "12-01-2016",
            delivery_timeslot: "10am-3pm",
            order_id: "16853",
            address: "140,Bajanai koil street, Melmanagar,Poonamallee,Chennai",
            _id: "56938584db988e241102d194",
            ordered_at: "2016-01-11T10:35:48.911Z",
            status: "UnderProcess"
        },
        {
            can_name: "Hapserve",
            can_quantity: "6",
            can_cost: "150",
            delivery_date: "11-01-2016",
            delivery_timeslot: "10am-3pm",
            order_id: "17397",
            address: "133,Bajanai koil street, Melmanagar,Poonamallee,Chennai",
            _id: "569385bbdb988e241102d195",
            ordered_at: "2016-01-11T10:36:43.918Z",
            status: "UnderProcess"
        },
        {
            can_name: "Bisleri",
            can_quantity: "5",
            can_cost: "250",
            delivery_date: "11-01-2016",
            delivery_timeslot: "10am-3pm",
            order_id: "14218",
            address: "133,Bajanai koil street, Melmanagar,Poonamallee,Chennai",
            _id: "56939a13c898ef7c0cc882b0",
            ordered_at: "2016-01-11T12:03:31.324Z",
            status: "Cancelled"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here i need to retrieve every document where delivery date is today

so this is my nodejs route

```
router.get('/booking-date/:date', function(req, res){
        var id = req.params.date;
        RegisterList.find({'booking.delivery_date':id}, {'booking.$':1}, function(err, docs){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            res.json(docs);
        });
    });
```

while am using this am not able to get every data. only two data is retrieve from collection.

example if i search for a date 11-01-2016 am getting only one subdocument for 
each parent id, but in the above json for date 11-01-2016. for one parent id has 2 subdocument for that date and another parent id has 1 subdocument for that date.

am not able to write mongoose query retrieve to every subdocument where matches done..
Help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may want to try the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** where you can **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** the booking array with a filter made possible using the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)**, **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** and **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operators.

The **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator inspects each element within the `booking` array and the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator returns only the wanted fields based on a true condtion, a false value is returned on the contrary instead of the array element. **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator then removes all false values from the array by comparing to another set with the [false] values, the final result is only the returned matches:

```
router.get('/booking-date/:date', function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.date,
        pipeline = [
            {
                "$match": { 'booking.delivery_date': id }
            },
            { 
                "$project": {        
                    "booking": { 
                        "$setDifference": [
                            { 
                                "$map": {
                                    "input": "$booking",
                                    "as": "el",
                                    "in": {
                                        "$cond": [
                                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.delivery_date", id ] },
                                            "$$el",
                                            false
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            [false]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ];

    RegisterList.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, docs){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Comment: how can i add another condition in above answer @chridam

Comment: @Nodemon Please create a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

The $ projection operator projects only first matching element, refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

Project all subdocuments {bookings: 1},then filter subdocuments within your application.